# How to add extra named routes definitions in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm upgrading RoR app from 4.0 to 4.2.
In 4.0 we have had url_helpers which added extra url_helpers like so:

```
module UrlHelper
  def subscribe_url (tenant)
    url_options = {
       :controller => "users/subscription",
       :action     => "new",
       :only_path  => false,
       :subdomain  => tenant.sitename
    }
    url_for url_options
  end
end
```

Then our base_controller would just include them:

```
class BaseController < ActionController::Base
  # Gives us access to custom resource paths and overrides url_for
  # to provide support for multitenancy.
  include UrlHelper
```

However, after updating to Rails 4.2.11.3 it stopped working.
Our tests seem to  seem to unable to access subscribe_url anymore even so it's included in base_controller.

```
expect(response).to redirect_to subscribe_url(tenant: tenant)
```

Fails with:

```
undefined method `login_url' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UsersRegistrationsController
```

Is there a different way to add url_helpers to rspec tests?

Unfortunately, cannot use `direct` routes as it's not Rails 5, yet.

Comment: On a side note - never add spaces between the name of a method and the parents in ruby. Since parents are optional it's treated as `def subscribe_url((tenant))` and adding any additional arguments will cause a syntax error since it's not actually a list.

Answer (score 0):

After the helper method defined you must reboot the server. Click [here](https://www.rubyguides.com/2020/01/rails-helpers/)!

Comment: Which server? I cannot access them in rspec